# Finding indirect paths between two nodes in NEO4j

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher

I'm using cypher query to find the paths between two nodes using cypher query

```
Match p =  (n{ConceptID: 'C0000039'})-[r]-()-[s]- (m) 
WHERE r.RelationLabel CONTAINS "may_be_treat" or s.RelationLabel CONTAINS "may_be_treat"
RETURN p
```

But this query can return path with maximum depth of 2, how can I give path as variable(2,3,4,5,6) in this query, with condition as  r.RelationLabel CONTAINS "may_be_treat"

Comment: I think you can use the `variable length` notation for that: `(n)-[*1..5]->(m)`: find all `n` and `m` nodes connected with a path length no more than 5. I can recommend to use the [cheatsheet](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/).

Comment: @MarcoL but then this query does not include the filter condition, which is what I require

Comment: `r` should be connected directly to `n` and `s` directly connected to `m`, right?

Comment: I just used "s" for creating a path length of 2, because . Ideally I don't require "s"

Comment: All relationships between `n` and `n1` should have a property `RelationLabel` that contains "may_be_treat"? Or ony one is enough? I believe that is a good ideia edit the question and put on it a sample data set and the desired output.

Comment: @BrunoPeres all relationships have property RelationLabel and at least one of the  relationship should have RelationLabel as may_be_treat

Comment: @gaurav1207 right. Take a look in my answer, I believe it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [variable-length pattern matching](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength).

If you need that all relationships between `n` and `n1` have a property called `RelationLabel` that `CONTAINS` the value "may_be_treat", then you can use the [ALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all) function in conjunction.

```
Match p =  (n{ConceptID: 'C0000039'})-[*]-(m) 
WHERE ALL (r IN relationships(p) WHERE r.RelationLabel CONTAINS "may_be_treat")
RETURN p
```

If only one relationship with `RelationLabel` that contais "may_be_treat" is enough, then you can use [ANY](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-any) function instead.

```
Match p =  (n{ConceptID: 'C0000039'})-[*]-(m) 
WHERE ANY (r IN relationships(p) WHERE r.RelationLabel CONTAINS "may_be_treat")
RETURN p
```

Comment: Is there a way to faster this query? because when I increase the depth of the path the query takes forever to execute and in my case I have multiple relations between a set of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

[@Bruno Peres' answer is right.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45961817/2964675)
To build on top of that if you want to have control over the length of the path you can either add an explicit variable-length pattern matching

```
Match p =  (n{ConceptID: 'C0000039'})-[*1..5]-(m) 
WHERE ANY (r IN relationships(p) WHERE r.RelationLabel CONTAINS "may_be_treat")
RETURN p
```

or use the [`length`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/list/) Path function.

```
Match p =  (n{ConceptID: 'C0000039'})-[*]-(m) 
WHERE length(p) < 5 AND ANY (r IN relationships(p) WHERE r.RelationLabel CONTAINS "may_be_treat")
RETURN p
```